# jquery mobile textarea causes error

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page (version 1.3.1) which is exhibiting strange behaviour

I'm trying to use a text area If I put

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

on the page I get the error

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js:4

If I remove

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

the error disappears

I get the same error with

```
<textarea  cols="40" rows="8" name="message1" id="message1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

will be thrown if jQuery version older then 1.7 is used.

Function **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** was introduced in version 1.7

Comment: It's about jQuery mobile and he already mentioned v 1.3.1

Also, this would not explain that the error occures when he adds a textarea, or am i missing something?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is nothing more then an extension of jQuery, just like jQuery UI. Function on is a common jQuery function used for event binding. jQuery Mobile uses jQuery for literally everything. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: that's it thank you - I  switched to jquery 1.9.1 and problem solved